# How to restore internet explorer 11 configuration when creating new VM from vhd?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, regedit, sysprep

I need a reliable procedure for the following problem i'm facing:
I created win 10 vm in azure, changed browser setting and then created vhd from it. When i create new VM from that image, every single modification that i made was gone because of sysprep.
How can take a snapshot of the this configuration and apply it on the new VM's that i create? I tried to use tools like regshot but it gives me a lot of changes.

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour].  Not a good question by the way you asked it.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a Snap Shot through Power shell:

**Get the VHD disk to be copied.**
$disk = Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $dataDiskName

**Create the snapshot configurations.**
$snapshot =  New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $disk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location $location

**Take the snapshot.**
New-AzureRmSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshot -SnapshotName $snapshotName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

If you plan to use the snapshot to create a Managed Disk and attach it a VM that needs to be high performing, use the parameter -AccountType Premium_LRS with the New-AzureRmSnapshot command. The parameter creates the snapshot so that it's stored as a Premium Managed Disk. Premium Managed Disks are more expensive than Standard. So be sure you really need Premium before using that parameter.

For more information, see the [Create a VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json) from a snapshot sample.